# React Hooks State is only updating once Type:error not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have attached screen shots of my code and the error I am getting.

Here is the overview; I am new to using hooks and am trying to get my to-do-list checkboxes to save in state to be equal to true when checked and false when unchecked. The first click on a checkbox works and updates in state, but every subsequent attempt to check or uncheck a box results in a **TypeError: prevState.map is not a function** (see image 2).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HX04.jpg) image 1 : checking the box and it works fine and updates state.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG295.jpg) image 2: Attempted to click on a checkbox again resulting in the map error.

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAmt1.jpg) image 3: Main app code.

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEMvp.png) image 4: To-Do-list component code.

I am confused as to why my code will not work and am asking for help in fixing this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, post the code as text. If possible, put a minimal example at codesandbox or another online sandbox. It seems that what you import from './todosData.js' is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a function to `setList`, you always have an up-to-date value of your state as the first parameter. After the first time you use it, you are returning an object `{ updatedTodos }`. You should return the array `updatedTodos`. You don't even need to declare a variable in this case, just use the short arrow return:

```
setList(prevState => prevState.map(todo => {
    if (todo.id === id) {
        return {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
    }
    return todo
}))
```